# MATLAB and Raster Plots

Tags: matlab, plot, raster

I've looked through all raster related things on stackoverflow for Matlab and have not been able to find a useful and easy way for making a raster plot of some data.

The raster plot I want to make uses the following vector:

```
X =[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;]
```

in this vector, a 0 = no response and a 1= a response. Each element also represents 0.1s. I want to make a plot that represents the data as a raster in the following way:

| ||| | | | |||||| | | |

---> Time
(note: this example does not correspond to the data I have given)

where Time is on the X-Axis and each line corresponds to a 1 (i.e. a response). Does anyone have some suggestions on how to do this?

I did use Matlab's command for a sparsity plot, but it is not quite what I am looking for. Also, I tried linalg::raster but I do not have the toolbox this command requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your drawing I assume you are looking for

```
stem(X,'Marker','none')
```

And for the time axis you could do something like

```
t = (1./(24.*60.*60.*10)).*(1:length(X)) ;
stem(t,X,'Marker','none') 
datetick
```

Comment: Looks like it to me.  If you really need to rasterize this, you can just save it or use `getframe` then `frame2im`.  +1

Comment: Hi. This worked; however, do you know if there is a way to make multiple raster plots, say 60 of them, and stack them such that they all share the same X axis?

Comment: There are examples about using multiple data series with `stem` in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/stem.html). Alternatively you can try [hold](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hold.html).